# Declaring AuthenticationManager Bean throws exception "Cannot apply DaoAuthenticationConfigurer to already built object"

Tags: spring-security

My `UserServiceImpl` class extends the `UserDetailsService` interface, and i have overriden the `loadUserByUsername()` method, I declared an `AuthenticationManager` bean, and using the builder, passed it my `userDetailsService` implementation and preferred password encoder.

Here's my security config class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class UserManagmentConfig {
    
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    return builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).and().build();
}
}
```

And my WebAuthorization config :

```
public class WebAuthorizationConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

This is the exception i get when launching the app :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [app/ticketme/securityconfig/UserManagmentConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@14d513ca to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at app.ticketme.Main.main(Main.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@14d513ca to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@14d513ca to already built object
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.add(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:182) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.apply(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:125) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder.apply(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java:280) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java:182) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$DefaultPasswordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:291) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at app.ticketme.securityconfig.UserManagmentConfig.authenticationManager(UserManagmentConfig.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at app.ticketme.securityconfig.UserManagmentConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a7378581.CGLIB$authenticationManager$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at app.ticketme.securityconfig.UserManagmentConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a7378581$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2537ee3.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at app.ticketme.securityconfig.UserManagmentConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a7378581.authenticationManager(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Sadly, most of the youtube tutorials use the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, what am i doing wrong here ? any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you enable formLogin, the framework will build a authentication manager for you with the supplied beans that you instantiate.

Why you are building your own authenticaation manager i have no idea.

So lets go through the steps, when you select you want to use `formLogin` the framework creates an authentication manager with the beans you have provided. You have provided a `passwordEncoder` and you should also provide an implementation of the `UserDetailsService` interface. This should be supplied like a bean as such:

```
@Bean
CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService() {
    return new CustomUserDetailsService();
}
```

Spring will then create a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and stick your password encoder in it and your custom `UserDetailsService`.

And your error message tells me that since you have already built a generic provider, the framework cant add more stuff to it.

You should read how to enable form login in the documentation [FormLogin Spring security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html)

and basically remove:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    return builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                  .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                  .and()
                  .build();
}
```